# Installing VSTO Outlook Add-in with a fixed GUID using VSTOInstaller

Tags: vsto

I have an Outlook Add-in that we are trying to distribute via SCCM.
The problem is that we are not getting a consistant GUID for each install.
If we use the setup.exe then it always generates the same GUID, but SCCM won't uninstall using the setup.exe.
Hence we have to use

```
VSTOInstaller.exe /i
VSTOInstaller.exe /u
```

However VSTOInstaller always gives a different GUID which confuses SCCM.

Does anyone know if there is a way to force the GUID?

Maybe through some xml in the .VSTO file?

Comment: What is your command line? Why do you need to use the `VSTOInstaller.exe` utility instead of MSI?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an MSI installer for your Office add-in. See [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2019) for more information.